# StaticMatic setup: error with Compass integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compass-sass, staticmatic

I'm getting an error when attempting to setup a new StaticMatic project. After utilizing:

```
$ staticmatic setup my_site
```

I am getting the following output with an error which seems to be generated by Compass:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/app_integration.rb:27:in `lookup': No application integration exists for staticmatic (Compass::Error)
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:44:in `configuration_for'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.1/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:22:in `add_configuration'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/staticmatic-0.11.1/lib/staticmatic/compass.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/staticmatic-0.11.1/lib/staticmatic.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/staticmatic-0.11.1/lib/staticmatic.rb:20:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/staticmatic-0.11.1/lib/staticmatic.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/staticmatic-0.11.1/bin/staticmatic:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby193/bin/staticmatic:19:in `load'
    from c:/Ruby193/bin/staticmatic:19:in `<main>'
```

I am on a Windows 7 machine, and I currently have the following gems installed:

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    actionmailer (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    actionpack (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    activemodel (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2)
    activerecord (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    activeresource (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    activesupport (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.2.2)
    acts_as_commentable (3.0.1)
    addressable (2.2.7, 2.2.6)
    ancestry (1.2.5)
    ansi (1.4.2, 1.4.1)
    arel (3.0.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.1)
    authlogic (3.1.0)
    aws-s3 (0.6.2)
    babosa (0.2.2)
    bborn-acts-as-taggable-on (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
    bigdecimal (1.1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.7, 0.0.5)
    builder (3.0.0)
    bundler (1.1.3, 1.0.21)
    capybara (1.1.2)
    childprocess (0.3.1)
    chunky_png (1.2.5)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2, 3.1.1)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
    coffee-script-source (1.3.1, 1.2.0)
    compass (0.12.1)
    compass-rails (1.0.1)
    configatron (2.9.0)
    desert (0.5.4)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    disguise (3.0.2)
    dynamic_form (1.1.4)
    erb2haml-win (0.1.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0, 1.2.13)
    factory_girl (3.1.0, 2.3.2)
    factory_girl_rails (3.1.0, 1.4.0)
    faker (1.0.1)
    faraday (0.7.6)
    ferret (0.11.5 mswin32)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    foreigner (1.1.6)
    friendly_id (3.2.1)
    fssm (0.2.8.1)
    guard (1.0.1)
    guard-rspec (0.7.0, 0.5.5)
    haml (3.1.4)
    haml-rails (0.3.4)
    heroku (2.24.0, 2.18.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    hpricot (0.8.6, 0.8.5)
    htmlentities (4.3.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    io-console (0.3)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2, 2.0.0, 1.0.19)
    json (1.6.6, 1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.5.4)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
    koala (1.4.0)
    launchy (2.1.0, 2.0.5)
    log4r (1.1.10)
    macaddr (1.5.0)
    mail (2.4.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.0)
    meta_search (1.1.3)
    mime-types (1.18, 1.17.2)
    minitest (2.12.0, 2.5.1)
    multi_json (1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.4)
    multi_xml (0.4.2)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
    net-ldap (0.2.2)
    netrc (0.7.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.2 x86-mingw32)
    oa-basic (0.3.2)
    oa-core (0.3.2)
    oa-enterprise (0.3.2)
    oa-more (0.3.2)
    oa-oauth (0.3.2)
    oa-openid (0.3.2)
    oauth (0.4.5)
    oauth2 (0.5.2)
    omniauth (0.3.2)
    paperclip (2.4.5)
    pg (0.13.2 x86-mingw32, 0.12.2 x86-mingw32)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    prototype-rails (3.2.1)
    pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1, 1.3.6, 1.0.1)
    rack-cache (1.2, 1.1)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
    rack-openid (1.3.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
    rack-test (0.6.1)
    rails (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
    rails_autolink (1.0.6)
    railties (3.2.3, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.2)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rakismet (1.1.2)
    rdiscount (1.6.8)
    rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
    recaptcha (0.3.4)
    RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
    rflickr (2006.02.01)
    ri_cal (0.8.8)
    rmagick (2.12.0 mswin32)
    rspec (2.9.0)
    rspec-core (2.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.1)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0)
    ruby-openid (2.1.8)
    ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
    ruby_parser (2.3.1)
    rubygems-update (1.8.21, 1.8.15)
    rubyntlm (0.1.1)
    rubyzip (0.9.6.1, 0.9.5)
    sanitize (2.0.3)
    sass (3.1.15, 3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.1.6, 3.1.5)
    selenium-webdriver (2.20.0)
    sexp_processor (3.1.0, 3.0.10)
    sprockets (2.4.0, 2.1.2, 2.0.3)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5 x86-mingw32, 1.3.3 x86-mingw32)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
    staticmatic (0.11.1)
    systemu (2.5.0)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    test-unit (2.4.8)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    tinymce-rails (3.4.9)
    treetop (1.4.10)
    turn (0.9.4, 0.8.3)
    tzinfo (0.3.33, 0.3.32, 0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1)
    uuid (2.3.5)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    win32console (1.3.0 x86-mingw32)
    xml-simple (1.1.1)
    XMLCanonicalizer (1.0.1)
    xpath (0.1.4)
    yamler (0.1.0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like `staticmatic` is not compatible with the newer `0.12.x` version of `compass`. To fix it uninstall `compass (0.12.x)`, and install `compass (0.11.7)` instead:

```
gem uninstall compass
gem install compass -v 0.11.7
```

That should fix it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I thought I had tried that, but looking back through my gem list, it turns out I had uninstalled the wrong version of compass. +1!